# How getServletName() works in Java?

Tags: servlets, servletconfig

Out of curiosity I was looking at the HttpServlet class's code and found that its parent class "GenericServlet" defines the method "getServletName()" declared in the interface "ServletConfig".
However the GenericServlet's getServletName() method makes a call to "sc.getServletName()" if the ServletConfig's object "sc" is not null. I could not understand how this thing works since it seems to be calling itself when I do a ctrl+click in eclipse to see the implementation of the method! There is no overridden implementation in the HttpServlet class too!

Here is a snapshot of the GenericServlet's implementation :

```
public String getServletName() {
    ServletConfig sc = getServletConfig();
    if (sc == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
            lStrings.getString("err.servlet_config_not_initialized"));
    }

    return sc.getServletName();
}
```

Can anybody enlighten me on this..

Comment: It is not calling it self. The GenericServlet is calling servletConfig.getServletName() not this.getServletName(). It happens that GenericServlet for ease implement also ServletConfig interface, but it isn't servletConfig. It is getting serveltConfig object via it's init(ServletConfig config) method. And then in the getServletName() method it is just acting as a proxy to pass this call to the config.getServletName() method.

What you don't understand here??

Comment: Yes you are right @Gas but what I am not getting is how is it returning the servlet's name since ServletConfig's getServletName() is just an abstract method. Also if we ctrl+click on "sc.getServletName()" in GenericServlet class to see its implementation it would take us again to the same method! I want to know from where is the String (Servlet's name) is returned in essence..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`javax.servlet.GenericServlet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.java#GenericServlet.init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29) implements the `ServletConfig` interface but it does not contain the actual implementation for `ServletConfig`.It uses delegation by using `config` object, which is provided by the **`container`** while invoking the `init` method.

[`GenericServlet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.java#GenericServlet.init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29) takes `ServletConfig` object (which is a [`StandardWrapperFacade`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.catalina/com.springsource.org.apache.catalina/7.0.26/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardWrapperFacade.java) obj for tomcat ) as a parameter for [**`init(ServletConfig config)`**](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.java#GenericServlet.init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29) method and store its reference to the instance variable **`config`** when invoked by **`container`**.

- **Init method**

  ```
   public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
   this.config = config;//assign config to the instance variable
   this.init();
   }
  ```
- **getServletName method**

  ```
  public String getServletName() {
     ServletConfig sc = getServletConfig();//returns the ref of instance variable i.e. config
      if (sc == null) {
          throw new IllegalStateException(
             lStrings.getString("err.servlet_config_not_initialized"));
      }

      return sc.getServletName();//call method on config object
    }
   }
  ```

  Therefor it's not calling the **`getServletName()`** on current instance( **`this`**) instead it's calling it on **`config`** object which is passed by the **`servlet container`** while initialing the servlet.

You should also look at the [**servlet Life-Cycle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet#Life_cycle_of_a_servlet).

For tomcat [`org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.catalina/com.springsource.org.apache.catalina/7.0.26/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardWrapper.java#StandardWrapper.getServletName%28%29) provides the actual implementation of `ServletConfig` interface.

**UPDATE:-**

If you want to get the name of underlying class then you could use [**`object.getClass().getName();`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) method.

Comment: Thanks @Vikrant
I was also thinking the same that the actual implementation must be somewhere else.. and as you cleared, its in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper for Tomcat where it makes another call to getName() to return the name. :)

I guess previously my question was misunderstood that the call was recursive, I said so because on doing ctrl+click in eclipse on sc.getServletName() it took me to the same method! Anyways, thanks :)